# Why is halitzah mandatory and is subsequent marriage allowed?

Tags: halacha, marriage, beit-din-court, yibbum-chalitza-levirate

Some *batei din* make *halitzah* mandatory and do not allow levirate marriage, even threatening jail if the surviving brother refuses *halitzah* and wants a levirate marriage.

1. What is the law if the couple marries anyway?
2. What is the law if the couple marries AFTER *halitzah*?

Comment: relevant: [Why don't some do yibum today, l'chatchilah?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/41126/11501) (seems to suggest *yibum* is still performed amongst *Sefaradim*)

Comment: Israeli law is off topic

Comment: I looked into this, they cannot marry after halitza, will post details when question is reopened but see [MT Hilchot Yibum 1:12](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/960619/jewish/Yibbum-vChalitzah-Chapter-One.htm). As I wrote above in my first comment, *yibum* is not universally outlawed, I even know person (*Sefaradi*) who performed it

Comment: @MauriceMizrahi see https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/11202/what-did-sephardic-jews-do-when-yibum-required-taking-a-second-wife/84810#84810 which elaborates when Yibbum would be allowed for Sefardim, and see https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/53019/what-should-a-woman-who-can-only-do-chalitza-do-if-her-yevam-cant-do-it/89866?r=SearchResults&s=1|7.6773#89866 which qualifies even Ashkenazim to do Yibbum when not being able to do Chalitza but everyone agrees that after chalitza it is forbidden (chayav Malkus) to marry that sister in law though the marriage does work Yevamos 10b

Comment: after chalitsa it's eshet achiv shelo bimkom mitsva Karet @mbloch

Comment: @kouty no its not kareis it's a _lav_ of _shuv lo yibone_ and even though its assur Kiddushin works mbloch and user16454 are correct see Yevamos 10b

Comment: Ah! Good, I learned this and missed it

Comment: @yosefkorn right. I reviewed it now. The other wives indeed are karet for the other brothers according to Resh Lakish and not for Rabbi Yochanan. But the cholets himself is only belav. Yshar koach

Answer (score 1):

The Poskim say that even in a situation where we would allow Yibbum for example the brother has amputated legs above the knee Rachmana Litzlan and how much more so when we don't allow Yibbum and he did it anyway, after the brother has done Yibbum he must divorce her straight away.

> נקטעה רגלו מעל הברך, לדברי הכל חליצתה פסולה; ועל היבם לייבם את האשה **ולהוציאה אחר כך בגט** בשו"ת שרידי אש, ח"ג סי' מט, בדעת גדולי האחרונים - שבות יעקב, בית מאיר, חת"ס, הגר' חיים עוזר גרודזנסקי, וכן כתב באו"ז סי' תרסה, בשם ריב"ן

After Chalitza if that brother or any other brother want to marry her through *Kesef Shtar Biah* (see Kidushin 2a) with *Eidim* (Yibbum no longer applies Yevamos 10b "Shuv Lo Yibane"), the Marriage does take effect as this relationship is no longer Chayav Kareis (see Kiddushin 66b) But it is a forbidden relationship which is either *Chayav Asei* (transgressing a positive Commandment) according to Shulchan aruch Even haEzer 162,2 and Rashi Yevamos 10b, or *Chayav Lo Taase* according to Tosfos and Bach Beis Shmuel and Beer Heitev. There is a 3rd opinion of the Rambam that there is only a prohibition *derabannan* to marry one's *Chalutza* see Beis Shmuel [here](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%90%D7%91%D7%9F_%D7%94%D7%A2%D7%96%D7%A8_%D7%A7%D7%A1%D7%91_%D7%91)